# Use proc glimmix for binomial response-Model statement

Tags: sas, proc

Usually we use the following statement

```
    model y/n = block variety / dist=binomial solution;
```

However, if I have already calculate proprtion=y/n by EXCEL and directly use "proportion" into SAS. i.e

```
    model proportion = block variety /dist=binomial solution;
```

I get the same result.

However, is there anything wrong with my second code?

Answer (score 0):

You are suppose to get the same result as you have said too. So it is not clear what went wrong with your code!